# From a PHP array to a form

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

I have a PHP function that automatically stores the position of various objects.

```
$(function(){
    $("#sortable").sortable();
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        //var dataItem = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize");
        //alert(dataItem);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'save-sorting-position.php',
            data : dataItem,
            success: function(data) {                
                alert('Positions saved');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

They are then stored in save-sorting-position.php, which consists of:

```
<?php 
$arr = unserialize($_REQUEST["item"]); 
foreach($arr as $index => $position)
{
    //store the position here
}
?>
```

I want to pass this array into a form. I tried using something like this (in the actual form):

```
<?php 
foreach($position as $pos)
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="' . $position . '>' 
} 
?>
```

But things didn't work out. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: <?php 
foreach($position as $position)
{  echo '<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="' . $position . '>' } ?>

what difference is there for things inside foreach loop ?
Both are same

Comment: I've corrected it to foreach($position as $pos)

Comment: When I load the page in-browser, I get `' } ?>` printed in the actual page content, for some reason.

Comment: Semi colon at the end of echo

Comment: Are you sure that your JS serialize operation is producing serialized data in PHP's own serialize format? Why not use JSON so you know what you're getting?

Comment: @MarcB how would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a semi colon at the end of the echo statement and also you have started the double quotes for value = but you din't end it. Correct that

```
<?php 
foreach($position as $pos)
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="' . $pos . '" />'; 
} 
?>
```

Inside foreach echo statement try using it as $pos instead of $position

Comment: Made modifications but still getting `'; } ?>` printed in browser.

Comment: I don't think so. Because this is where it gets printed. Did you change the quotes as I have said ?

Comment: Here's the code for the whole page at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tehsockz/fJB8F/), albeit without the other php functions.

Comment: When I put it in there I get `E_NOTICE: [type: 8] -- Undefined variable: position -- at line 50 



E_WARNING: [type: 2] -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -- at line 50`; that's because I haven't uploaded the PHP functions, though...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here you are overwriting original `$position` variable:

```
foreach($position as $position)
```

do like:

```
foreach($position as $pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
foreach($position as $pos)
{  echo '<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="' . $pos . '">'; } ?>
```

**Syntax**

```
foreach($arr as $val)
```

You were echoing $position wrongly instead of $pos

Comment: I don't get an error message; rather, `'; } ?>` is printed in-browser.